# Around Spring AOP on target method with void return type skips code execution

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-aop

To my understanding, `@Around` annotation on Spring AOP can handle any return type on methods; with `void` type returning null.

This is a simple advice to log duration of a method:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Profiling { }
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class ProfilingAspect {
    // ...

    @Around("@annotation(profilingAnnotation)")
    public Object logDuration(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Profiling profilingAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = joinPoint.proceed(); // on void methods, this supposed to return null
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            throw e;
        } finally {
            long endTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(); // Below is not ran all together

            long duration = endTime - startTime;
            logger.info(joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString()+": "+duration+"ms");
        }

        //return the result to the caller
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, when invoked on this method, it doesn't return anything and instead skips every code after `proceed()` altogether. Even `finally` block.

This is the problematic code:

```java
@GetMapping("/members/exportpdf")
@Profiling
public void exportToPDF(@RequestParam(required = false)String role, HttpServletResponse response) throws DocumentException, IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<List<GuildMember>> guildMembers;
    if (role==null) {
        guildMembers = guildService.findAll(); // Async Method
    } else {
        guildMembers = guildService.findByType(role); // Async Method
    }

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "inline; filename=guildmembers_" + currentDateTime + ".pdf";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    PDFExporter exporter = new PDFExporter(guildMembers);
    exporter.export(response).get(); // exporter.export(..) is an Async method returning CompletableFuture<Void>
}
```

How is this possible? Am I missing something here on the configuration? Or is it a bug on Spring?

Note. I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.4 with starter dependencies

Edit. `PDFExporter.export()` uses `OutputStream` on `HttpServletResponse` to print `application/pdf` to the user and returns `CompletableFuture<Void>`. As to why, the method communicates with the async functions above, as such I want to guarantee the operation is finished somehow.

Comment: The aspect looks OK, your problem is probably elsewhere. E.g., the final line of code says _"`exporter.export(..)` is an `Async` method returning `Void`"_, which makes little sense, because `Void` does not have any `get()` method. That should not even compile. Or does the method actually return a `Future` of something? Still, why would you call `get()` on the future then in the final line of a method returning nothing? Do you want to enforce the asynchronous operation to somehow be synchronous in order to guarantee that the export is finished before `exportToPDF` terminates?

Comment: @kriegaex I'm sorry, I should've clarified more about that code. It uses `OutputStream` on `HttpServletResponse` to print `application/pdf` to the user and returns `Future<Void>`. As to why, the method communicates with the async functions above, as such I want to guarantee the operation is finished somehow.

Comment: I tested your code on my workstation, creating some dummy classes and method where you omitted them. Just like I expected, the aspect works flawlessly. There must be an error in the code you chose to omit from the question. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then either edit your question in order to provide one or post a link to a GitHub repository containing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to teach you what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how to better ask questions here, I am going to show you the MCVE I created according to your code fragments and description:

**Dependency classes we need in order to make the code compile:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Profiling {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

public class GuildMember {
  private String name;

  public GuildMember(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "GuildMember{" +
      "name='" + name + '\'' +
      '}';
  }
}
```

**`PDFExporter` utility:**

Maybe you are using the `PDFExporter` from PrimeFaces, but that is just a guess. In any case, it seems not to be a Spring component, because later you call the constructor instead of getting a bean instance from the application context. So I am modeling it here as a simple POJO too.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class PDFExporter {
  CompletableFuture<List<GuildMember>> guildMembers;

  public PDFExporter(CompletableFuture<List<GuildMember>> guildMembers) {
    this.guildMembers = guildMembers;
  }

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<Void> export(HttpServletResponse response) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      return null;
    });
  }
}
```

**Service with `@Async` methods:**

Next, I was making an educated guess about what your guild service might look like:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Service
public class GuildService {
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<List<GuildMember>> findAll() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      return Arrays.asList(new GuildMember("Jane"), new GuildMember("John"), new GuildMember("Eve"));
    });
  }

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<List<GuildMember>> findByType(String role) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      return Collections.singletonList(new GuildMember("Eve"));
    });
  }
}
```

**Component to be targeted by profiling aspect:**

Here is your sample component, only slightly streamlined with regard to `guildMembers` initialisation. But it does not change the functionality at all:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
  @Autowired
  private GuildService guildService;

  @GetMapping("/members/exportpdf")
  @Profiling
  public void exportToPDF(@RequestParam(required = false) String role, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<List<GuildMember>> guildMembers = role == null ? guildService.findAll() : guildService.findByType(role);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "inline; filename=guildmembers_" + currentDateTime + ".pdf";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    PDFExporter exporter = new PDFExporter(guildMembers);
    exporter.export(response).get();
  }
}
```

**Driver application + `@EnableAsync` configuration:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ExecutionException {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ExecutionException {
    MyComponent myComponent = appContext.getBean(MyComponent.class);
    myComponent.exportToPDF("admin", new MockHttpServletResponse());
  }
}
```

**Profiling aspect:**

Last, but not least, here is the aspect. It is also the same you presented, only a bit less complicated concerning how to return the result. But again, this does not change the fact that the aspect works as expected:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q66958382;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.Instant;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ProfilingAspect {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfilingAspect.class);

  @Around("@annotation(profilingAnnotation)")
  public Object logDuration(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Profiling profilingAnnotation) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    try {
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw e;
    }
    finally {
      long duration = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - startTime;
      logger.info(joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString() + ": " + duration + " ms");
    }
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

If you run the application, the console log says:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2021-04-06 09:18:10.793  INFO 13616 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q66958382.DemoApplication     : Starting DemoApplication on Xander-Ultrabook with PID 13616 (C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground\target\classes started by alexa in C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground)
(...)
2021-04-06 09:18:14.809  INFO 13616 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-06 09:18:14.812  INFO 13616 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q66958382.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 4.815 seconds (JVM running for 7.782)
(...)
2021-04-06 09:18:15.839  INFO 13616 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q66958382.ProfilingAspect     : MyComponent.exportToPDF(..): 1014 ms
(...)
```

So if it does not work in your own application, either there is something different from how you described it or you are misinterpreting the log.

Comment: This is actually really close to the current code implementation. It turns out the problem was a bad handling in async `CompletableFuture<Void>`, where it never called terminal functions such as `supplyAsync()` or `complete()`.

Comment: Happy to help. Lesson learned: Always post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need help, because if you cannot solve your own problem, you also cannot know if it is hidden inside the snippets you chose to select for sharing or elsewhere. If you knew, probably you would not need help in the first place.